# Where is this tower?

Tags: identify-this, architecture, quebec

I came across this photo from some family trip apparently in 1988. When I first saw it immediately reminded me of northern California / bay area. But the date doesn't correspond at all to any trip we took there. I'm not even sure if this is in the US although would be be most likely.

The second "8" in "1988" looks a little vague to me, I wonder if it could be a "0" or even a "3". But that probably wouldn't change much about the scene.

Hopefully this is a distinctive-enough building & setting that someone will recognize it.

[image]

[Full size version](https://i.ibb.co/KytCS1j/Image-6.png).

Comment: For future reference, a lot of Quebec churches have tin roofs like the one in the photo

Comment: I initially thought it looked like Stanford University's Hoover Tower--in northern California.

Comment: @JohnMcGehee I think that was indeed the CA landmark I was thinking of...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is the [Édifice Price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89difice_Price) in Quebec City, Quebec, Canada. The pic was taken from the [Citadelle of Quebec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citadelle_of_Quebec), view goes to north.

[Here's a view from Streetview](https://goo.gl/maps/kHEeog7YuutfK56d6) from almost the same camera position (vegetation has changed):

[image]

### Pictures of Édifice Price from Wikimedia Commons:

Similar view like pic in question:

[image: Édifice Price - Christophe.Finot / CC BY-SA (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5)]
<sup>Source: Wikimedia Commons - Christophe.Finot / [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5)</sup>

Detail view of Édifice Price:

[image: Édifice Price - Cephas / CC BY-SA (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)]
<sup>Source: Wikimedia Commons - Cephas / [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. We did take a Quebec trip in that time period, which I'm now reminded of :)